# Client server messages in a loop

Tags: java, sockets, client, communication, server

I want to send two messages at least from the client to the server and the server then responds to these messages. However only one message is sent from the client and the server also responds to one any idea where i am wrong
This is my server.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class server
{

    private static Socket socket;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {

            int port = 25000;
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Server Started and listening to the port 25000");

            //Server is running always. This is done using this while(true) loop
            while(true)
            {
                //Reading the message from the client
                socket = serverSocket.accept();

                InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String sub = br.readLine();

                //string parsing
                String delims = "[.]";
                String[] tokens = sub.split(delims);    
                System.out.println("You have subscribed to  "+tokens[1]);
                String returnMessage="Subscription message received.";

                //Sending the response back to the client.
                OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
                bw.write(returnMessage);
                System.out.println("Message sent to the client is "+returnMessage);
                bw.flush();

                InputStream iss = socket.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isrr = new InputStreamReader(iss);
                BufferedReader brr = new BufferedReader(isrr);
                String subb = brr.readLine();
                System.out.println("Regular message received from client is "+subb);



                OutputStream oss = socket.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter osww = new OutputStreamWriter(oss);
                BufferedWriter bww = new BufferedWriter(osww);
                bww.write(subb);
                System.out.println("Message sent "+subb);
                bww.flush();


            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                socket.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){}
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my client.java

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
    import java.net.InetAddress;
    import java.net.Socket;

    public class client

    {

    private static Socket socket;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            String host = "localhost";
            int port = 25000;
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
            socket = new Socket(address, port);

            //Send the subscription message to the server
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

            String subscribe= "Subscribe.nust";
            String sendMessage = subscribe + "\n";
            bw.write(sendMessage);
            bw.flush();
            System.out.println("Message sent to the server : "+sendMessage);

            //Get the return message from the server
            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String message = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Message received from the server : " +message);

            //Send the regualar message to the server
            OutputStream oss = socket.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter osww = new OutputStreamWriter(oss);
            BufferedWriter bww = new BufferedWriter(osww);

            String regular= "Because of the APS Peshawar attack that took place on 16th December 2014, nust is facing security issues.";
            String sendMessage2 = regular + "\n";
            bww.write(sendMessage2);
            bww.flush();
            System.out.println("Message sent to the server : "+sendMessage2);

            //Get the return message from the server
            InputStream iss = socket.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isrr = new InputStreamReader(iss);
            BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(isrr);
            String msg = br1.readLine();
            System.out.println("Message received from the server : " +msg);

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            //Closing the socket
            try
            {
                socket.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 'returnMessage' is missing a line terminator?

Answer (score 0):

Don't keep creating new `BufferedReaders/Writers` on the same socket. Use the same ones for the life of the socket. You're losing data in their buffers.